# PHP Regex Match Multiple Occurrences in Multiple Lines String

Tags: php, css, regex

I have this multiple lines CSS style:

```
.style-1 {
    border-color: #2980B9;
}

.style-2 {
    background-color: #2980B9;
    #FFF;
}

.style-3 input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #2980B9;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

And here is my regex pattern: `\..*\{\s?\s?+.*\s?\}\s?\s?+`

https://regex101.com/r/tP7qE7/1

I want to match each rule from the selector until the closing bracket so I can prepend new selector to each rule and echo each rule separately. Right now with my regex pattern above I can get only the first rule. I tried both `preg_match()` and `preg_match_all()` but with no success. How can I match each rule using regex?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex (`\..*?\{.*?\}`) with `g` and `s` modifiers:

```
/\..*?\{.*?\}/gs
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tP7qE7/2)

Comment: Thank you! This is finally how I do it in PHP: `preg_match_all( "#[\.|\#].*?\{.*?\}#s", $css, $matches );` g modifier is not recognized so I have to use `preg_match_all()`

Comment: You can change it to `preg_match_all( "#[.#].*?\{.*?\}#s", $css, $matches );` .. no need to escape characters inside character set `[ ]` and no need of `|` .. it is bydefault applied inside it.. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
\..*?\{\s?\s?+[\s\S]*?\s?\}\s?\s?+
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tP7qE7/3

Answer (score 0):

you can try this pattern to match the selector

```
(?s)^\..*?\{.*?\}$
```